# Intersection of List of lists Haskell

Tags: haskell

I must write a function that returns the intersaction of more than 2 lists

```
Ex: intersection[[1,5,3,11],[1,5,2,11],[5,3,2,11]] = [5, 11]
intersection:: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
intersection= undefined
```

I discovered that exists a function intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] ( but it's available only for 2 lists :)

Comment: There"s this nifty `+` operator that adds two numbers, but what if I want to sum up an entire list?

Answer (score 4):

When you notice a function with the form `a -> a -> a`, you're possibly dealing with a function that can be used with a monoid, which means you can use folds.

In your case, there isn't really a reasonable output for `intersection []`, so you should use a fold function that requires a non-empty input list, such as [`foldr1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr1).

Therefore, an easy implementation would be:

```
intersection:: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
intersection = foldr1 intersect
```

Comment: It's cool to see some faces from the JavaScript tag here doing `.reduce()` trick. Well... I guess `foldr1` is the MOAR (Mother of all Reduces"). +

Comment: @Redu Haha, yep. I've been learning Haskell in order to recognize when to use certain patterns in JavaScript. It's been quite a great lesson.

Comment: What is the monoid involved in your solution ? I cannot think of an `mempty` here.

Comment: @Jean-BaptistePotonnier There isn't a monoid being used here, just half of one. A fold can be done using the `mappend` portion of a monoid. My first sentence was just stating a useful intuition.

Comment: @Jean-BaptistePotonnier `Endo` seems a plausible candidate. Without the newtype wrappers, `mempty = id; mappend = (.)`. Applying `foldMap intersect` to the list `[x,y,z]` would then give you `intersect x . intersect y . intersect z`. It's only a few short steps from there to the actual desired function.

Comment: Though `Endo` is kind of cheating, no?  There's a semigroup staring us in the face.

Answer (score 3):

Intersection of two sets is *associative* (and *commutative*, but it is less important here). I.e.:

```
intersect(A, B, C) = intersect(intersect(A,B), C) = intersect(A, intersect(B, C))
```

It means that it doesn't matter in which order you do the intersection operation, the result won't change.

So in Haskell you can utilize the `foldl1` function to apply the `intersect` function over all of the list:

```
> import Data.List
> foldl1 intersect [[1,5,3,11],[1,5,2,11],[5,3,2,11]]
[5,11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy approach pro tip:

pro tip:

Intersection of 2 lists is obvious.

Intersection of 3 lists is intersection of 3rd list with intersection of first 2 lists.

So what do you have to do is to remember your current intersection result and intersect it with next list until you run out of lists or till your intersection will be empty.

Better approach in terms of complexity would be using merge sort like approach.

Where your threat lists like elements of list and instead of comprehension use intersect on elements and return an intersection of them.

Merge operation would be an intersection too.

It's been a long time since i had anything to do with Haskell so unfortunately I won't be able to provide you with code sample.